# how insert the same id to other table?

Tags: laravel

I have a table and it is like auto increment, I tried to do something like this: in an order table you insert for example your id, product name, value, and delivery address, and I needed it in another table called the order id and insert it in the order details.
using this method

```
$order = new order;
        $order->id_user = 1; //$iduser;
        $order->name_destain = $request->name;
        $order->state = 1;
        $order->total = $request->total;
        $order->created_at = Carbon::now();;
        $order->updated_at = Carbon::now();;
        $order->save();
```

Comment: after `$order->save();` you can find the id by `$order->id;`

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like, I assume that the name of other table is order_details and its model is OrderDetail.php

```
        $order = new order;
        $orderDetailObj = new OrderDetail; // or you can insert it in existing one OrderDetail::find($id); here $id is the particular (primary key)id of OrderDetail
        $order->id_user = 1; //$iduser;
        $order->name_destain = $request->name;
        $order->state = 1;
        $order->total = $request->total;
        $order->created_at = Carbon::now();;
        $order->updated_at = Carbon::now();;
        if($order->save()){
            $orderDetailObj->order_id = $order->id_user
            $orderDetailObj->update();
            return true;   
        }
```